# In IE8, my homepage is redirected by my router to if I don't have a connection. I have to reopen IE to get access. How can I fix this?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, redirection

I open IE, and the router then redirects to 192.168.0.1 from Google. This is the config page, to try to fix the connection. In time, the connection fixes, but clicking refresh doesn't get me on to Google, and neither does the top right search bar. The only thing I've found that works is reopening IE. I think that IE 'learns' in some way that Google's IP is 192.168.0.1. How can I persuade it that it's wrong, without reopening.

Ideally, I'd like a fix which I only have to do once. I've got VC++ 2010, so if there's a short Add-on I need to write, I can.

#### Edit:

It turns out that I don't always need to restart IE. Opening new tabs, I got the sequence Google, Router, Google, Router, Google, Google. Odd or what?

#### Edit 2:

Just to be clear, I'll give an exact example. I opened IE8, and the home page *www.google.co.uk/* was redirected to *192.168.0.1/sky_information.html*. I then noticed that the status light on my router had turned green, so I clicked Refresh, and got the normal page for *192.168.0.1*, which went to *www.google.co.uk/sky_router_status.html*, which loaded sucessfully with  a status page on my router. I then opened a new tab, and went to *www.google.co.uk/*, which loaded sucessfully, and which I used to reach this page.

Comment: This sounds like IE is set to use a proxy. More information is known, but I promise you that IE has 'not learned Google is 192.168.0.1" IE does not have that ability, and besides that would be caused by an underlind DNS problem. This seems like a user configuration problem to be honest.

Comment: What makes you think this is the router redirecting you?

Comment: @Ramhound Looking at [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Change-proxy-settings-in-Internet-Explorer), I'm fairly sure I'm not on a proxy. The router is sort of like a proxy, but it's working fine; I'm happy to live with the problem.

Comment: @Dave - I'm sent to its page. Surely I'd get an HTTP error otherwise?

Comment: @GKFX - I know you're being directed TO the router home page, but I'm asking if you know it's BY the router. Any thing can redirect you to a routers home page... The router, the ISP, malware etc.

Comment: @DaveRook - The first redirect takes me to a page on the router saying 'Your internet connection is not available, please try again in a few minutes.' This behaviour would make complete sense. I don't have malware (according to MS Security Essentials).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like malware. Or a corrupted hosts file.

Run a malware scan and AV scan.

Check nothing strange is in your hosts file C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc (open with notepad)

Open up the router and check to ensure no redirecting or blocking of pages exists.

Open IE, click tools, Internet options. Click on Connections tab, LAN settings - is this checked under Proxy?

Comment: I've removed everything except localhost in HOSTS, I'm not on a proxy, my router settings are fine, and I've started a scan; no help so far.

Comment: In that case I would phone your ISP - they can do this (in the UK, I know for a fact Plustnet do it).